# Aggregate values pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, na

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
Id A B C D

1 a b c d
2 a b   d 
2 a   c d
3 a     d
3 a b c
```

I want to aggregate the empty values for the columns B-C and D, using the values contained in the other rows, by using the information for the same Id.

The resulting data frame should be the following:

```
Id A B C D
1 a b c d
2 a b c d 
3 a b c d
```

There can be the possibility to have different values in the first column (A), for the same Id. In this case instead of putting the first instance I prefer to put another value indicating this event.

So for e.g.

```
Id A B C D   
1 a b c d
2 a b   d 
2 x   c d
```

It becomes:

```
Id A B C D   
1 a b c d
2 f b c d
```

Comment: Why `x` become `f`?

Comment: Take a look at [`pd.Groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html).

Comment: Is 'f' a random value since a and x differ for ID 2?

Comment: Maybe the mean between `a` and `x`?

Comment: F is just a value that stand for “this id has 2 different value in column A”, just a flag. F when an id has different values in column A for different rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `groupby_agg`:

```
>>> df.groupby('Id')
      .agg({'A': lambda x: x.iloc[0] if len(x.unique()) == 1 else 'f',
            'B': 'first', 'C': 'first', 'D': 'first'})

    A  B  C  D
Id            
1   a  b  c  d
2   f  b  c  d
```

Comment: In the second case how can I put another letter for an id that has different values in column A? In this case Id 2 has values a and x in column A. How can I put letter f in the second data frame in column A for id 2?

Comment: @Will. I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think to do this is to iterate through each unique `Id`, slicing it out of the original dataframe, and constructing a new row as a product of merging the relevant rows:

```
def aggregate(df):
    ids = df['Id'].unique()
    rows = []
    for id in ids:
        relevant = df[df['Id'] == id]
        newrow = {c: "" for c in df.columns}
        for _, row in relevant.iterrows():
            for col in newrow:
                if row[col]:
                    if len(newrow[col]):
                        if newrow[col][-1] == row[col]:
                            continue
                    newrow[col] += row[col]
        rows.append(newrow)
    return pd.DataFrame(rows)
```